# Elasticsearch - exporting to CSV using jq

Tags: json, elasticsearch, export-to-csv, jq

I am exporting data from Elasticsearch to CSV. I have taken my JSON code from the request element of a visualisation, executed it through a curl XGET search and piped it to jq. My question is around how jq is handling this output. 
Skipping the jq part for a moment, the output of the search shows the aggs has several layers. E.g.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/kibana_sample_data_flights/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"aggs": {"2": {"date_histogram": {"field": "timestamp","interval":"30m","time_zone": "Europe/London","min_doc_count": 1},"aggs": {"3": {"terms": {"field": "FlightDelayType","size": 5,"order": {"_count": "desc"}}}}}},"size":0,"_source": {"excludes": []},"stored_fields": ["*"],"script_fields": {"hour_of_day": {"script": {"inline": "doc['timestamp'].value.hourOfDay","lang": "painless"}}},"docvalue_fields": [{"field": "timestamp","format": "date_time"}],"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"match_all": {}},{"match_all": {}},{"range": {"timestamp": {"gte": 1542804577190,"lte": 1542890977190,"format": "epoch_millis"}}}],"filter": [],"should": [],"must_not": []}}}'
```

A snippet of the output to highlight my question:

```
"aggregations" : {
"2" : {
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key_as_string" : "2018-11-21T12:30:00.000Z",
      "key" : 1542803400000,
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "3" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "No Delay",
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          {
            "key" : "Weather Delay",
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

I cannot seem to get my jq code to transverse down to the layer under "3". What I actually want to send to CSV here is the key Flight Delay Type (e.g. Weather Delay) and the count. (Note I have left out the -r and | @CSV for testing.)
My jq code so far:

```
jq '.aggregations[].buckets[]'
```

That returns:

```
    {
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key_as_string": "2018-11-21T12:30:00.000Z",
      "key": 1542803400000,
      "doc_count": 2,
      "3": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "No Delay",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "Weather Delay",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

How can I get that next layer down?

TIA

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines more closely.  A valid JSON example in the hand is worth two invalid JSON snippets in the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Drilling down from the top:

```
.aggregations[].buckets[]["3"].buckets[] | select( .key == "Weather Delay")
```

yields:

```
{
  "key": "Weather Delay",
  "doc_count": 1
}
```

### Or ...

... if you're willing to take the risk:

```
.. | select(.key? == "Weather Delay")
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that has been helpful.

That has now given me .aggregations[].buckets[]["3"].buckets[] - (I had the formatting around "3" incorrect.)

I realised I also need to include the first key entry. I thought I could put that simply as .aggregations[].buckets[] | [.key] | .aggregations[].buckets[]["3"].buckets[] | [.key, .doc_count"] but it does not work.
With both fields called key I can't see how I can select both values. So output data would read:

1542803400000, Weather Delay, 1

(I have the formatting to CSV working nicely, just the data extraction)

TIA

Comment: If you are asking a new question, consider creating a new SO question. Otherwise it would help if you revised this Q to clarify what the revised question is, with supporting data in acordance with the [mcve] guidelines.